# How do I fix a messed up rbenv install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, rbenv

I am still new to development and did not realize that I wasn't supposed to install rbenv while rvm was installed. I installed rbenv following the git instructions and now rails doesn't work at all... I am getting all kinds of weird errors and am trying to fix it to no avail. I have tried removing rvm and rbenv and then reinstalling rbenv but that doesn't seem to help with anything. Here is my latest error:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:raffler Ryan$ bin/rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /Users/Ryan/code/raffler/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:332:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Users/Ryan/code/raffler/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EACCES)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:332:in `open'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:332:in `write_pid'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:raffler Ryan$
```

Any suggestions for how to fix the mess I got myself into would be amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the error message you actually have permissions issues not a rails issue. Try doing a `chmod -R 666 /Users/Ryan/code/raffler/` and making sure your user is the owner of that directory.